# How to customize carrier name in iOS 6 simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios6, xcode4.5

How can I customize the default `Carrier` name to something else, e.g. `AT&T`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is a way to change the carrier name without using any objective c code or image editor app: https://github.com/toursprung/iOS-Screenshot-Automator/blob/master/changeCarrierName

This solution works great with all versions of iOS (including iOS 6 and 7)

The key point is

`sudo plutil -convert xml1 SpringBoard.strings`

We don't necessarily have to convert it back to binary code since Mac OS accepts both formats.

After you converted your file to XML, you can easily edit the file with vim or any other editor of your choice.

**UPDATE**:
I uploaded a detailed description on how to update the carrier name: https://github.com/toursprung/iOS-Screenshot-Automator/blob/master/changeCarrierName

Comment: This link seems to have broken. Any help?

Comment: I updated the link to my tutorial: https://github.com/toursprung/iOS-Screenshot-Automator/blob/master/changeCarrierName

Comment: Just wanted to let you guys know, the new path for iOS 7 is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/en.lproj

Comment: Despite this being the accepted solution, Anson's answer below is far simpler.

Comment: new path for iOS 11 is: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/en.lproj/SpringBoard.strings

Answer (score 18):

Copy and paste into terminal, replacing DERP with your carrier string:

`find -E /Applications/Xcode.app -iregex '.*/en(glish)?.lproj/SpringBoard.strings' -exec sudo /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Set :SIMULATOR_CARRIER_STRING DERP' {} \;`

Finds relevant files and modifies them in place. No copying files, converting binary to xml, or editing strings in other applications.

Comment: Super!! This fixed it for me! Actually im considering putting this command in a small osx app so devs can easily change it! Thanks mate! so simple!

Comment: this works in 2023

Answer (score 6):

You can use [this hack](https://gist.github.com/3035167), just compile the `XCDFakeCarrier.m` file in your project and change the `FakeCarrier` constant to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is a perfect app for this called Status Magic that I was beta testing.  Just trying to find a link for it...

You import a screenshot and it removes all the carrier specific text from it and replaces it with a standard status bar and you can edit the time, carrier info, etc...

Means you don't have to use Photoshop or anything.

Will be back with a link...

**LINK**
https://itunes.apple.com/uk/app/status-magic/id547920381?mt=12

**EDIT** Just found out that the app is still in review fro the Mac App Store.  Should be out soon.  It really is perfect for what you are wanting to do though.  And really easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Status Magic looks interesting. Here is the link to the App Store version: https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/status-magic/id547920381?mt=12.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible with iOS Simulator (If it's even possible you have to dig deep :) ). The best way is to take the screenshot (Command+S), and change the image in Adobe Photoshop, or some image processing program like that.