# How to change Carrier text in both 8.x and 9.x simulator?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios9, ios-simulator

I have followed answer by KrauseFx and Anson [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580694/how-to-customize-carrier-name-in-ios-6-simulator), but the only simulator changed is iOS 10 simulator, not 8.x and 9.x.

How to change `Carrier` text in both 8.x and 9.x simulator?

Comment: https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic, this works on all the platform.

Comment: @New16 I missed this great repo!

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by editing this file:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/French.lproj/SpringBoard.strings
As the path suggests, I'm French. Switch to whichever localization you choose.

Inside this strings file (editable with XCode if it's a binary plist), you'll find a SIMULATOR_CARRIER_STRING key. Change its value, fire up your simulator, and there you go.

Comment: Note that doing this will invalidate the signature of Xcode.app which will cause delta updates from the Mac App Store to fail to apply.  You'll end up downloading a delta, failing to apply, then downloading the full installer.  If you do this, make sure you change it back (exactly) before updating to a newer version of Xcode.